# Static generation with Next.js: Pass page props to Layout component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use getStaticProps for my Layout component as described [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16684#discussioncomment-132479), but do struggle to solve this for my specific case:

_app.tsx

```
const NoCheck: React.FC = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const neoPage = Component as NeoPage
  const LayoutComponent = neoPage.Layout || Layout

  const { withAuthCheck = true } = neoPage

  const CheckAuthComponent = withAuthCheck ? CheckAuth : NoCheck

  return (
    <CommonProviders pageProps={pageProps} overmindConfig={config}>
      <CheckAuthComponent>
        <LayoutComponent>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </LayoutComponent>
      </CheckAuthComponent>
    </CommonProviders>
  )
}

export default App
```

LayoutUnauthorized.tsx

```
export const LayoutUnauthorized: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  systemNormal,
}) => {
  return (
    <Flex>
      <SystemStatus systemNormal={systemNormal} />
      {children}
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

Login.tsx (in /page)

```
export const Login: NeoPage = () => {
  return (
    ...
  )
}

Login.Layout = LayoutUnauthorized
Login.withAuthCheck = false

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://company.com")
  const systemNormal = await res.ok

  return {
    props: {
      systemNormal,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}
```

So Layout has a property I would like getStaticProps to pass. How can this be achieved?

Comment: From `getStaticProps` I would like to pass the status of another web page to the layout component. I have added more details above

Comment: @juliomalves is it clear now?

Comment: Still not entirely clear to me. What specific value do you want to access in `getStaticProps`? Can you not declare/import the value in that file and access it within `getStaticProps`?

Comment: My question is not what I want to access within `getStaticProps`. It is, how can I pass `systemNormal` from `getStaticProps` to `LayoutUnauthorized` here: `Login.Layout = LayoutUnauthorized`?

Comment: It's clearer now. You have access to `systemNormal` from `pageProps` in `App`. You could just pass it as a prop to `LayoutComponent`.